# Restricting hangouts to be used through different organizations

Tags: javascript, security, google-apps, administration, google-admin-sdk

Helping a company that is using Google Apps to improve its security between different departments, They want to restrict using Google hangouts in Google apps across different organizations on the same domain.

I tried easily at first to go through the Administrative settings and there was only disabling the hangouts in organizations. Same as written [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60767?hl=en)

Then I tried to go through the [Hangouts](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/) APIs which had nothing to do with restrictions so I went through the [Admin Settings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/) APIs, Yet could not find anything helpful.

My thoughts are either I can do such thing through some APIs - Right or wrong? - or somehow I can find some work around in building different hierarchy for the organizations.

Straight forward question, How can I restrict chatting and video hangouts between people in different organizations on Google Apps?

Comment: If you can't do it in the admin console you probably won't be able to do it using an API.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. You cannot prevent people from chatting with each other via Google Talk or Hangouts within the same Google for Work account.

With the Sharing settings for the Talk/Hangouts service (where this setting would be if it existed), you can only prevent users from chatting with people outside the Google for Work account itself, not different OUs.

This also wouldn't be possible with the current APIs.